# bash tab-completion: complete full path on single tab in git commands?

Tags: bash, git, tab-completion

Whenever I tab-complete a file path after a git command in bash, e.g. `git add`, I have to press `<TAB>` multiple times to complete to the actual filename, depending on how many subfolders there are up to the file.

Example: I want to add the file `my/example/file`, then I enter:

```
git add <TAB>
git add my/<TAB>
git add my/example/<TAB>
git add my/example/file
```

This is the case even when `my/example/file` is the only changed file and hence the only current tab-completion option. In this case bash could as well complete the full path with the first `<TAB>` already, but it doesn't.

[fish](https://fishshell.com/) actually does this by default:

```
git add <TAB>
git add my/example/file
```

Is there a way to configure this behavior in bash as well?

Comment: say there are 100 dirs (including subdirs) and 1000 files then how do you want it work?

Comment: Tab completion in bash is fully programmable. Just grab the completion code you're using, look at it to see what options it has for this, and if it doesn't have the options you want, add them.

Comment: This is great. When someone posts the answer I'm going to use it. ;)

Comment: @pynexj It should complete all subdirs as far as the path it not ambigous, instead of completing each subdir separately. Just like fish does it.

Comment: For anyone who's interested: I got a solution to this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716164/317320